# Transition and Function call on button press

Tags: kivy

I want to show a waiting screen while doing some stuff in the background. Actually, the screen does not show the waiting screen although the root.transition.current works correctly.

## .py file

```python
import sys
import time
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock

kv = '''
<MyScreenManager>:
    AcceptShutdown:
    Waiting:

<AcceptShutdown>
    name: 'acceptShutdown'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'Do you really want to exit?'

        Button:
            text: 'OK'
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'down' #these three
                root.manager.current = 'waiting'           #lines are
                Clock.schedule_once(root.shutdown, 5)                    #the problem

<Waiting>
    name: 'waiting'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Take a break.'
    '''

Builder.load_string(kv)

class Waiting(Screen):
    pass

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class AcceptShutdown(Screen):
    def shutdown(self, time):
        sys.exit()
    pass

class Shutdown(Screen):
    pass

class Panel(App):

    sm = MyScreenManager()

    def build(self):
        return self.sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Panel().run()
```

It calls the function but it does not change the screen.
When I only do the transition (without the function call afterwards), it has the expected result. The screen shows the waiting screen.
Doing it the other way round (only function call without transition) also this works.

Hopefully, someone can help me out.

Comment: Please post a minimal *runnable* example. But the obvious question is, what did you do to make `dostuffinbackground()` actually do its stuff in the background?

Comment: This is a part of the GUI from my cocktailmachine. While the waiting screen is visible I want to clean the pumps. This takes a while and I don't want to show the acceptshutdown screen with the frozen buttons.

Comment: I edited the initial post. Now it is runnable. It starts with the acceptshutdown screen and the button press should show the waiting screen. The background functionality is just waiting 5 sec. Also the real process will be ended after the function, so I don't care about returning to any other screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `time.sleep(5)` does exactly what it says: the Python process sleeps for 5 seconds instead of updating the gui to reflect the changes you just made.

Instead, use `Clock.schedule_once(root.shutdown, 5)` and make `shutdown` expect an argumuent that it can ignore (Clock.schedule_once passes the time since the scheduling as an automatic argument). This will insert root.shutdown as something for Kivy to do later, without blocking the drawing loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I edited the starting post again. But now I get an error that "name Clock is not defined". I imported Clock so I think the problem is that I use it inside of the kivy file. When I write an extra function def foo(self, time){sys.exit()} and call it within the shutdown function with your proposed Clock.schedule_once(self.foo, 5) it works quite well. Do you have a solution for this tiny problem?

Comment: Use `#:import Clock kivy.clock.Clock` to import the name within the kv file, per [the documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html).